# Trigger to only add users above a certain age to a table?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'd like to write a trigger (using MySQL) that checks if a user is above a certain age before entering the record into the users table. Otherwise, don't enter the record into the table.

I initially tried a `CHECK` constraint but that doesn't allow for stored procedures, functions etc, so I'm trying a trigger.

So far, I have

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER t_age_check
BEFORE INSERT
ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE dob DATE;
    IF
        YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), dob))) + 0 >= 18 THEN
        INSERT INTO users
    END IF
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct or efficient. I've never written a trigger before (and I'm very new to SQL) but I think I understand it *in theory*. Any help on fixing this or better alternatives would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it in reverse. The trigger is invoked by an INSERT, so there's already an insert in progress. You can *cancel* the insert by some condition in the trigger, but if the data is valid, then just let it continue.

Reference the columns of the current row that is trying to insert by using `NEW.<column_name>`. I assume your `users` table has a `DATE` column named `dob`.

For example:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER t_age_check
BEFORE INSERT
ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.dob > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Users must be at least 18 years of age';
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Testing:

```
insert into users set dob = '2005-04-11';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

insert into users set dob = '2008-04-11';
ERROR 1644 (45000): Users must be at least 18 years of age
```